# Session Values are not coming

Tags: php, html, session

I have a homepage.php and messages.php page for both common "menu.php" is there so I have started a session in homepage.php as well as messages.php And I have not started any session in menu page.
I am trying to get these values here is my menu code:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-at" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class=" name-caret">
        <?= $_SESSION['name'] ?><i class="caret"></i>
    </span>
    <img src="../images/user/<?= $_SESSION['image'] ?>" style="width:100px; height: 61px;">
</a>
```

**HOME PAGE.PHP**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header('location:index.php');
}
include_once('includes/config.php');
include_once('includes/header.php');
include_once('includes/menu.php'); 
?>
```

so I can I show login user data of name and image on the menu for both homepage and messages page.

Comment: You need to session_start() on each page that you are using session variables.

Comment: in menu page too start session

Comment: drop `ob_start();`

Comment: @Dagon In all pages..?

Comment: Also are you sure your image path is coorect. once try with full path

Comment: If image path is wrong atleast name has to apper right..?

Comment: There are certain rules for using session. no need to start a session twice. in included pages. use session_start() only one time in the starting of the page, remove other session_start() where ever you include in your file. this may throw the warning.

Comment: Issue is Not getting values of name and image, warning are resolved. #fareed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use echo in PHP to show values. Like this:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-at" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <span class=" name-caret"><?php echo $_SESSION[name]; ?>
    <i class="caret"></i>
  </span>
  <img src="../images/user/<?php echo $_SESSION[image]; ?>" />
</a>
```

Comment: That's incorrect syntax. `<?=` tag already means `<?php echo`, so your syntax `<?= echo` is something like `<?php echo echo`. Also second error is to put variables in single quotes. That is just a string.

Comment: No you're still printing strings, not using variables.. Dude, don't post answers if you don't know basic PHP syntax. By the way, OP's syntax is valid.